# Why after() method of ClockTriggerBuilder runs incorrectly?

Tags: google-apps-script

**The trigger runs successfully,but it fires at incorrect time.**

I want to create the trigger about do-something after few seconds.

[Exmaple at the manual guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

But when I tried it for 1000 miliseconds,3000 miliseconds,

I found that when it be created ,it  must fired for-

waiting  for at least 1 minute.
.

.

.

I tried to use other method like ServiceHandler solution-

I found in Stackoverflow,but it was deprecated,

and nothing information at the Google App script guide.
.

.

.

Here is my code.

```
function test(){
<do something>
}

function trigger_test(){
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("test")
  .timeBased()
  .after(3 * 1000)  //fires function test() after 3s
  .create();
}
```

.

Is there my  misunderstanding about the method?

What should I do to solve the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: check with log statements or on the dashboard is it gets triggered or any error there in script

Comment: @Gaurav  Thanks your reply. The trigger runs successfully,but it fires at incorrect time.

Comment: If you want to run a function within a minute why call a trigger? Why not call the function directly or use `Utilities.sleep()`?

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks for your suggestion. Because I want to trace the function by `trigger event`,if I want it pause or stop at particular time manually.

Comment: [ClockTriggerBuilder.after()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#after(Integer)) is not guaranteed to a specific time, but within ±15 minutes of the time you specify.   `Utilities.sleep()` will should give you the delay you're looking for.

Comment: @HsinhsinHung, can you update the question with what is the current output of using [`after(3 * 1000)`]

Comment: Yes, the documentation shows +/- 15 min difference in exact time, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#after(Integer)

Comment: Perhaps you can use a client side solution by running set interval or set timeout from sidebar.